# Wix How to build 1 page where inventory is displayed and can be ordered on the same page

Tags: e-commerce, velo

Objective:  Build shop page on website that displays entire inventory and allows users to add items and quantities on the same page.

Current Situation:  Currently, customers go to Shop page then select a product which takes them to another page to add to cart.  If a customer wants to order mulitple items then have to click on each product to order then have to go back to shop page to select the next product to order and so on.

I would like the ability for customers to view and add on 1 page the inventory and their order.

See images screen shots I got from a website that I would like to build.

I am using wix.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with code. You'll need to use the [`addToCart()`](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/$w.CartIcon.html#addToCart) function.

You can see a great example of what you're trying to do, with code and even a site template, [here](https://www.wix.com/code/home/example/Add-to-Cart-Gallery).